# Apache: how to limit virtual dir to local network

Tags: security, apache, access-control, apache-config, lan

On my Apache 2.x server at home, I have a number of virtual directories.  I've set up my router so that I can access Apache from the internet.  I need to keep one of those virtual dirs (/private) from being accessed outside my home network LAN.  So given /private,  how do I configure Apache to only serve requests to /private from 192.168.4.x?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<Directory /users/me/private>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from 192.168.4
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: I tried the following:
Alias /private /users/me/private
<Directory /private>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from 192.168.4
    Deny from all
</Directory>

I restarted Apache yet I still can access the site via the Internet.  I tested it using my smartphone browser running on the Verizon network.  ??

Comment: Use the actual system pathname to the directory, /users/me/private, in the Directory config, or use a Location instead.

Comment: Using the actual path now give me a '403 Forbidden' error from both outside and inside of my network:
You don't have permission to access /private on this server.

Comment: Sorry, wrote the Order directive wrong.  Should be deny,allow.  Edited to fix.

Comment: (I do that sometimes since the semantics of the Order directive are the exact opposite of what they seem to me like they should be.)

Comment: How about if you want /private to be password protected instead? nvm: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PasswordBasicAuth